# Is there any way to make this code better?

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have TXT file with football results in this format:

```
1-0
2-0
2-3
etc...
```

I want to count each result to know how much of them are in this file. I have code to count it:

```
def find_result(self):
    file = open("results.txt", "r")
    result_00 = 0
    result_01 = 0
    result_02 = 0
    result_03 = 0
    result_10 = 0
    result_11 = 0
    result_12 = 0
    result_13 = 0
    result_20 = 0
    result_21 = 0
    result_22 = 0
    result_23 = 0
    result_30 = 0
    result_31 = 0
    result_32 = 0
    result_33 = 0
    result_other = 0
    results = 0
    for line in file:
        results += 1
        line = line.rstrip()
        if line == '0-0':
            result_00 += 1
        elif line == '0-1':
            result_01 += 1
        elif line == '0-2':
            result_02 += 1
        elif line == '0-3':
            result_03 += 1
        elif line == '1-0':
            result_10 += 1
        elif line == '1-1':
            result_11 += 1
        elif line == '1-2':
            result_12 += 1
        elif line == '1-3':
            result_13 += 1
        elif line == '2-0':
            result_20 += 1
        elif line == '2-1':
            result_21 += 1
        elif line == '2-2':
            result_22 += 1
        elif line == '2-3':
            result_23 += 1
        elif line == '3-0':
            result_30 += 1
        elif line == '3-1':
            result_31 += 1
        elif line == '3-2':
            result_32 += 1
        elif line == '3-3':
            result_33 += 1
        else:
            result_other += 1
    print('[0-0]' + str(result_00))
    print('[0-1]' + str(result_01))
    print('[0-2]' + str(result_02))
    print('[0-3]' + str(result_03))
    print('[1-0]' + str(result_10))
    print('[1-1]' + str(result_11))
    print('[1-2]' + str(result_12))
    print('[1-3]' + str(result_13))
    print('[2-0]' + str(result_20))
    print('[2-1]' + str(result_21))
    print('[2-2]' + str(result_22))
    print('[2-3]' + str(result_23))
    print('[3-0]' + str(result_30))
    print('[3-1]' + str(result_31))
    print('[3-2]' + str(result_32))
    print('[3-3]' + str(result_33))
    print('[OTHER]' + str(result_other))
    print('Matches: ' + str(results))
```

I think it is not good way to do this (i mean too much code), is there any better solution to do this? Thank You

Comment: @Jongware: that's not a valid off-topic reason. The question is *Too broad* for Stack Overflow (we can improve it in different ways), and we can perhaps point out Code Review as a better place to ask it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a more pythonic way you can use `collections.Counter` that is for this aim :

```
from collections import Counter
c_dic=Counter(open("results.txt", "r").readlines())
```

and you have a lot of choice for print your dictionary or items , as you have not a nested dictionary there is no need to loop over items and print them you can use `json.dumps` for print the dictionary with arbitrary indent :

```
from collections import Counter
import json
print json.dumps(Counter(open("newefile.txt", "r").readlines()),indent=4)
```

Comment: @Mateusz you're welcom ! ;)

Comment: i have another one question. What if i want to count and then assign to variable? I need it to do other things with them - that is why i used variables like result_00 etc.

Comment: As you have a dictionary you can access your values by indexing like `c_dic[0]` that is a more efficient way ,than initial a lot of variable !

Answer (score 4):

```
# import Counter for Counting the number of occurances of each items
from itertools import Counter

# Open the file for reading
with open("results.txt", "r") as input_file:

    # Create the counter object with the lines read from the file
    c = Counter(line.rstrip() for line in input_file)

    # Print the actual item (key) and the number of occurances (count)
    for key, count in c.items():
        print("[{}] - {}".format(key, count))

    # Find the total number of elements encountered, by adding all the counts
    print(sum(c.values())
```